# Timing a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a function that will time other JavaScript functions.

Basically, it would do something like this:

```
var start = new Date().getTime();

// the function

var end = new Date().getTime();
return end - start;
```

But, I'd like to be able to call it on any function.  For example, I could say `timeThisFunction(add)` or `timeThisFunction(subtract)` and it would see how long it took the functions `add` and `subtract` to run.

Is this possible in JavaScript?  I know there's scoping issues that could be involved.  What's the best way to implement it?

Comment: If you're interested in this for some serious purpose and not just as a learning project, you might want to check out [Benchmark.js](http://benchmarkjs.com/).

Comment: Use `performance.now()` instead of `Date()`. It is much more precise.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to be able to time a single call to a function, it's pretty easy:

```
function timer(fn) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();

  fn();

  var end = new Date().getTime();
  return end - start;
}
```

Passing functions around is no different than passing around any other sort of value.

If you need to time a function that requires parameters, just wrap it in another function:

```
var millis = timer(function() { theRealFunction(something, 22); });
```

The extra wrapper function will add a tiny amount of overhead, but it shouldn't matter for most purposes.

Similarly, if you need to time a function that expects `this` to be bound, you'd bind it before the call:

```
var millis = timer(someObject.someMethod.bind(someObject));
```

Now, all that said, if you've got a single JavaScript function call that takes enough time for this mechanism to give meaningful results, then there's probably some serious performance flaw worth investigating.

Comment: Hopefully the function doesn't return anything itself... `:P`

Comment: Yes, but what about those scoping issues? What if `fn` uses `this`?

Comment: @Juhana then bind it before calling the timer function.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an option, you could make timimng function to perform some work for you (context binding, arguments passing).

As a downside, `apply` is known to be slower then usual function call, so this will no be 100% accurate, but if what is needed is to compare two different implementations of the same function, then it can be useful.

```
function timeIt(fn, context) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2),
            start = new Date().getTime();

        fn.apply(context, args);

        return new Date().getTime() - start;

}
```

Example usage would be:

```
    function log(what, smthElse) { //ugly function for demonstration
        console.log(what + ' ' +  smthElse);
    };

    timeIt(log, null, 'hello', 'stranger');
```